# PHP+MYSQL Won't Insert Into Database

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Ok on my register page it just refreshes. My login lets you log in but my register just reloads the page.

Also I'm trying add a transaction code on it when you register

This is my register page code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ob_start();
session_start();

// Include DB
require('inc/Database.php');
$db = new Database();
$pageName = "Register";

// Include user class
include('inc/user.php');
$user = new User($db);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $_POST['username'] = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $_POST['username']);
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            // $password = $_POST['password'];
            $password = hash("sha256", $_POST['password']);
            $count = $db->count('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM members WHERE username = ?', array($username));

            if (!$count) {
                $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
                $result = $db->insert('INSERT INTO members (username,transaction,ownerIP,signupDate,password,email,active) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?)', array($username, $transaction, $ownerIP, $password, $_POST['email'], $activation));
                if ($result) {
                    $to = $_POST['email'];
                    $subject = "Welcome to ShareTracks!";
                    $body = "Thank you for registering at ShareTracks! The number one music app and community!\n\nActivate your account by simply clicking on the link below:\n\n http://sharetracks.net/activate.php?user=$username&code=$activation";
                    $additionalheaders = "From: accounts@sharetracks.net\r\n";
                    $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: accounts@sharetracks.net";
                    mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);
                    header('Location: login.php?action=joined');
                } else {
                    header('Location register.php?error=data');
                }
            } else {
                header('Location: register.php?error=taken');
            }
}
?>
```

This is my register html form:

```
        <div class="account-form">
            <form class="form-signup" role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                <h3><strong>Create</strong> your account</h3>
          <?php if($_GET['error'] == 'data') {
            echo '<center><div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> It seems you have entered invalid data, please sign up again using valid characters [A-Z/1-9].</div></center>'; 
          } ?>

          <?php if($_GET['error'] == 'taken') {
            echo '<center><div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> The username you have chosen is already taken. Try another one.</div></center>'; 
          } ?>                  
                <div class="append-icon">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']; ?>" class="form-control form-white username" required>
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="append-icon">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-white email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" required>
                    <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="append-icon m-b-10">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
                    <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control form-white password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
                    <input type="text" name="transaction" id="transaction" class="form-control form-white transaction" placeholder="PayPal Transaction" required>
                    <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                </div>                  
                <div class="terms option-group">
                    <label  for="terms" class="m-t-10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" data-checkbox="icheckbox_square-blue" required/>
                    I agree with terms and conditions
                    </label>  
                </div>
                <div class="m-t-20">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-rounded" data-style="expand-left">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <p class="new-here"><a href="login.php">Already have an account? Sign In</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the submit button it just refreshes the page.

Comment: Did you echo your query and see?

Comment: @Sa-7 said that you need to print the query. so instead of passing direct executing, first print out the query and run in mysql. I am sure you will find out your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your form action="" to your register page. Your current blank action makes it submit to the page that your form is on, not where your registration code is.  So it just refreshes the current page.

Answer (score -1):

Set action="" with the file name of your register page code

example :

if you have two different files one for form submission and the other one for register page code with file name "abc.php"

in your form submission action="abc.php"

Comment: He is using same page so no need to set action.